# How to run Java Eclipse from Excel VBA?

Tags: java, excel, vba, eclipse

I have written the following code in Java:

```js
public class test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        FileWriter f = new FileWriter(new File("C:\\Users\\john\\Desktop\\x.txt"));
        f.write("hello world!");
        f.close();
    }

}
```

It works correctly (creates a file called x.txt on the desktop containing "hello world!")

And I have this VBA script

```vb
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'

'
Dim objShell As Object
Dim JavaExe, JavaScript As String

Set objShell = VBA.CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")

JavaExe = """C:\Users\john\eclipse-workspace\eclipseCode\src\test.java"""
JavaScript = "C:\Users\john\Desktop\x.txt"

objShell.Run JavaExe & JavaScript

End Sub
```

But it does not execute the java code. It simply opens the file from java eclipse as a .txt file.

Is it possible to run java eclipse from Excel VBA? Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: I do not understand your question. You ask how to run eclipse from your VBA code. Then you say it opens, so it runs correctly. What exactly are you trying to accomplish? Or do you want to run a compiled Java program (aka class)?

Comment: Just a note: If you `Dim JavaExe, JavaScript As String` it will declare `JavaExe As Variant`. In VBA you need to specify a type for **every** variable: `Dim JavaExe As String, JavaScript As String` • You call your variable `JavaExe` but it does not contain the `Java.exe` but instead a jave source code that does not make any sense to me. Can you clarify that?

Answer (score 2):

What you want to implement in your "objShell.Run" is actually RUNNING Java from the command line with your program as an argument.

What you are ACTUALLY doing is pointing to the Java file and saying "Do this file" and the system is saying "OK. I know what to do with this. I open .java files in a text editor!".

Research how to compile & run java programs using javac/java.

To test this process, first ignore Eclipse and VBA and just go to a normal command prompt (cmd) and figure out the co mmands to compile & run the java to see what command line you need.

Hint: You will need to compile with javac & then run with java. Something like "javac test.java" and "java test" in the directory your file is in.

Should be straightforward from there.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The "javac test.java" and "java test" works in the command prompt, but I don't know how to include it in the VBA code. How should I do that?

Comment: Great! In your VBA Application, your variables JavaExe and JavaScript should point to your JRE's "java.exe" and the "JavaScript" should point to the directory and name of the file you were able to run in the command prompt.

If you change the WScript object's current working directory to the one you were in when you did the test commands, then it would be as simple as setting JavaExe to "java" and JavaScript to "test".. Maybe throw in some spaces for proper command line args.

Comment: Don't forget to "javac" your file if you change it.. or you can try to write it so it calls a "javac" first every time..

Comment: But what if the directory is different? So if I open a new excel file, put this macro there and run it, how do I specify the directory for JavaExe & JavaScript? Or do I need to change the directory of the Wscript object (and if so, how?) ? Thanks for your help btw!

Comment: You should do some reading on Environment and Working Directories as it relates to your VBA scripts. The environment usually has an assumed path and the path should have java's \bin directory in it, which means "java" shouldn't need to have a full path provided to it in many instances if it's installed correctly.Also if it makes any sense, the relative paths of the directories your macros run in should be relative to the file they are running in would be my guess. I'm not a macro guy so you should double check how it thinks about it.